# Multilevel Time-series Forecasting Model

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, forecasting, multilevel-analysis

I wanna do Demand Forecasting of product categories in different countries. The data structure of the data that I have is as follows:

- Date, **Country, Product Category** , Sales, and some additional measures.

so I would like to predict the sales for each product category in each country for the future, Which ML models can I use for that purpose?

Thanks in advance